# Action for adding a stroke to a shape and stroke should be the same color as the shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I have a huge number of shapes and need to add an outside stroke to almost all of them. So I am trying to create an action for it. The trouble I'm having is that the stroke should always have the same color as the color of the shape I'm putting the stroke on. At the moment I can only figure out how to do the action so that it always puts the same color stroke on every shape, or having to pause the action for input from myself.

Is there some way to sample or temporary save the color of the current shape so that I can use it?

Comment: Scripting time!

Comment: What is the point in adding a stroke to each of the shapes if it is going to be the same color? Surely you won't notice that it isn't there?